# What is the right way to use group by clause in MySQL with multiple conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am writing a query that will find the youngest student by each major if their average grade score is more than 80 and order them by their name from the following relation. I am using MySQL server and working with MySQL Workbench.

**Student**:

```
snum: integer
name: string
major: string
level: string
age: integer
```

**Class**:

```
cname: string
meets_at: time
room: string
fid: integer
```

**Grade**:

```
snum (foreign key)
name (foreign key)
score
```

Here is how I tried to implement the query.

```
select S.major, S.name, S.age
from student S , grades G
group by S.major
Having MIN(S.age) and G.score > (Select avg(G.score) 
                                from grades G1 , student S
                                where S.snum = G1.snum) ;
```

However this doesn't work and I am really confused about what the query should look like.

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(`snum` int, `name` varchar(18), `major` varchar(22), `standing` varchar(2), 
`age` int)
 ;

INSERT INTO student
(`snum`, `name`, `major`, `standing`, `age`)
VALUES
(578875478, 'Edward Baker', 'Veterinary Medicine', 'SR', 21),
(574489456, 'Betty Adams', 'Economics', 'JR', 20),
(573284895, 'Steven Green', 'Kinesiology', 'SO', 19),
(567354612, 'Karen Scott', 'Computer Engineering', 'FR', 18),
(556784565, 'Kenneth Hill', 'Civil Engineering', 'SR', 21),
(552455318, 'Ana Lopez', 'Computer Engineering', 'SR', 19),
(550156548, 'George Wright', 'Education', 'SR', 21),
(462156489, 'Donald King', 'Mechanical Engineering', 'SO', 19),
(455798411, 'Luis Hernandez', 'Electrical Engineering', 'FR', 17),
(451519864, 'Mark Young', 'Finance', 'FR', 18),
(351565322, 'Nancy Allen', 'Accounting', 'JR', 19),
(348121549, 'Paul Hall', 'Computer Science', 'JR', 18),
(322654189, 'Lisa Walker', 'Computer Science', 'SO', 17),
(320874981, 'Daniel Lee', 'Electrical Engineering', 'FR', 17),
(318548912, 'Dorthy Lewis', 'Finance', 'FR', 18),
(301221823, 'Juan Rodriguez', 'Psychology', 'JR', 20),
(280158572, 'Margaret Clark', 'Animal Science', 'FR', 18),
(269734834, 'Thomas Robinson', 'Psychology', 'SO', 18),
(132977562, 'Angela Martinez', 'History', 'SR', 20),
(115987938, 'Christopher Garcia', 'Computer Science', 'JR', 20),
(112348546, 'Joseph Thompson', 'Computer Science', 'SO', 19),
(99354543, 'Susan Martin', 'Law', 'JR', 20),
(60839453, 'Charles Harris', 'Architecture', 'SR', 22),
(51135593, 'Maria White', 'English', 'SR', 21);

CREATE TABLE grades
(`snum` int, `cname` varchar(23), `score` int);

INSERT INTO grades
(`snum`, `cname`, `score`)
VALUES
(574489456, 'Urban Economics', 45),
(567354612, 'Operating System Design', 98),
(567354612, 'Data Structures', 100),
(552455318, 'Operating System Design', 98),
(552455318, 'Communication Networks', 87),
(455798411, 'Operating System Design', 100),
(455798411, 'Optical Electronics', 87),
(348121549, 'Database Systems', 90),
(322654189, 'Database Systems', 97),
(322654189, 'Operating System Design', 56),
(301221823, 'Perception', 87),
(301221823, 'Social Cognition', 87),
(115987938, 'Database Systems', 100),
(115987938, 'Operating System Design', 98),
(112348546, 'Database Systems', 80),
(112348546, 'Operating System Design', 35),
(99354543, 'Patent Law', 65)
 ;
```

Expected Results:

```
+------------------------+----------------+----+---------+---+
| Computer Engineering   | Karen Scott    | 18 | 99.0000 | 1 |
+------------------------+----------------+----+---------+---+
| Computer Science       | Paul Hall      | 18 | 90.0000 | 1 |
+------------------------+----------------+----+---------+---+
| Electrical Engineering | Luis Hernandez | 17 | 93.5000 | 1 |
+------------------------+----------------+----+---------+---+
| Psychology             | Juan Rodriguez | 20 | 87.0000 | 1 |
+------------------------+----------------+----+---------+---+
```

Comment: *ind the youngest student by each department* : please show us the `department` table and how it relates to others.

Comment: There is no department, it was a mistake.

Comment: OK then. Would you please show us some sample data and expected output to help us understand your question? Please see [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for more details.

Comment: Ok, I added the schema details.

Comment: Nice. Now you would just need to add the expected results, and you will be all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that might work for your use case. The logic is to combine *aggregation* and *window functions*.

First, you can use a simple aggregate query to compute the average score of each student:

```
SELECT s.major, s.name, s.age, AVG(g.score) avg_score
FROM 
    students s
    INNER JOIN grades g ON g.snum = s.snum
GROUP BY s.snum, s.major, s.name, s.age
HAVING AVG(g.score) > 80
```

This will give you one record per student whose average score is higher than 80, along with his age, name and major, and average score.

Now all that is left to do is to select the youngest student in each group of students that have the same major. This can be done with window function `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT major, name, age, avg_score
FROM (
    SELECT
        x.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY major ORDER BY age) rn
    FROM (
        SELECT s.major, s.name, s.age, AVG(g.score) avg_score
        FROM 
            students s
            INNER JOIN grades g ON g.snum = s.snum
        GROUP BY s.snum, s.major, s.name, s.age
        HAVING AVG(g.score) > 80
    ) x
) z WHERE rn = 1
```

This **[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eZs7RioPmgrkCLJPxQbizq/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| major                  | name           | age | avg_score |
| ---------------------- | -------------- | --- | --------- |
| Computer Engineering   | Karen Scott    | 18  | 99        |
| Computer Science       | Paul Hall      | 18  | 90        |
| Electrical Engineering | Luis Hernandez | 17  | 93.5      |
| Psychology             | Juan Rodriguez | 20  | 87        |
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Can you explain what x.* refers to? Does it select all the attributes?

Comment: @a_a_a : welcome ! `x` is an alias for the aggregated subquery, and `x.*` means : all columns returned by the subquery.